# Shorten long conditions testing `if find_num_3 != None and find_num_3 != i and find_num_3 != j:

Tags: python

I have such a chain conditions testing:

```
if find_num_3 != None and find_num_3 != i and find_num_3 != j: #don't reproduce itself
```

In codes:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    num_1= nums[i]
    sub_target = target - num_1
    logging.debug(f"level_1_lookup: {lookup}")

    for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
        num_2 = nums[j] #
        num_3 = sub_target - num_2              
        find_num_3 = lookup.get(num_3) #             

        if find_num_3 != None and find_num_3 != i and find_num_3 != j: #don't reproduce itself    

            result = [num_1, num_2, num_3]
            triplets.append(result)

            logging.debug(f"lookup: {lookup} sub_nums: {nums[j:]} \nresult: {result}")
            logging.info(f"\ttriplets: {triplets}\n\n\n\n")                    
return triplets
```

How could transform the long chain to a compact short structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`if find_num_3 not in {None, i, j}`

Use set instead of list or tuple because it is more efficient to check element presence in a set. Complexity `~O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

Sets store their data as key/value pairs. The key is the hash of the stored object. It is the reason why you can't store multiple objects with same hash in a set. Presence checking in a set may sometimes be a little more than O(1) because of hash collisions.

[Here is a nice article to better understand hashes and sets.](https://www.asmeurer.com/blog/posts/what-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing-in-python/)

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @chepner, when values are known only at runtime (as in the question) using tuple is more efficient than using set since set instanciation is longer than tuple instanciation.

Comment: not very intuitive, this seem like a `None or i or j` .

Comment: I assume, this is wrong answer, cos, if x = None, so x in {None,i,j}, the codes will be executed.

Comment: @Alice This is using `not in`, not just `in`.

Comment: got it. @blhsing

Comment: amazing, could you give a link which explain the complexity O(1), I think it still need O(1) * 3.

Comment: @Alice O(1) * 3 *is* O(1).

Comment: Considering it takes O(n) time to build the set in the first place, it's debatable whether creating such a small set has any noticeable improvement over `[None, i, j]` or `(None, i, j)`.

Comment: @chepner I made i little benchmark for small set/list/tuple and set are still more efficient. https://gist.github.com/b6b346dc22cf9a7dc427ca46db1270f3

Comment: Your benchmarks use sets/tuples/lists that can be created as compile time; here, `i` and `j` are only known at run-time.

Comment: @chepner You are right. Tuples are slightly more efficient with runtime-only values.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to reduce the lines size, you could wrap your conditions into parenthesis:

```
if (find_num_3 is not None
        and find_num_3 != i
        and find_num_3 != j):
    # ...
```

---

you could store each condition value in variables, it is convenient because it names conditions and makes the final condition easily understable:

```
defined = find_num_3 is not None
not_i = find_num_3 != i
not_j = find_num_3 != j
if defined and not_i and not_j:
    #...
```

or:

```
if all(defined, not_i, not_j):
    # ...
```

---

you could also check if `find_num_3` is in a list of values or not:

```
if find_num_3 not in (None, i, j):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace by this :

```
if find_num_3 not in {None, i, j}:
    #...
```

Comment: Same answer with the previous one

Answer (score 0):

Not really answering your question as stated, but I think simplifying the nested loop is more interesting than shortening the already clear and direct comparisons of `find_num_3`. (Using a shorter variable name like `k`, which fits the pattern of `i` and `j` you are already using, shortens the comparison as well.)

```
from itertools import combinations

# ...

for i, j in combinations(range(len(nums)), 2):
    num_1 = nums[i]
    num_2 = nums[j]
    num_3 = target - (num_1 + num+2)

    k = lookup.get(num_3)
    if k is None or k == i or k == j:
        continue
    result = [num_1, num_2, num_3]
    triplets.append(result)
```